# vsftpd any password work for local users

Tags: authentication, vsftpd

My setup of vsftpd allows for local users to login using their usual passwords and another set of users to login through a passwd file.

The problem I have now is that when using a local user's login, then any password is being accepted and can let the user login (the logins using the passwd file are ok).

Here is the vsftpd.conf:

```
$ cat /etc/vsftpd.conf  | grep -v ^#
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=066
anon_umask=066
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES

chmod_enable=YES

chroot_list_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/ftp/$USER
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftp
```

And the /etc/pam.d/vsftpd file:

```
$ cat vsftpd | grep -v ^#
auth sufficient /lib/security/pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /home/ftp/passwd
auth    required    pam_shells.so
account required pam_permit.so
```

Not sure if there is any other relevant file I should post (?)

Answer (score 1):

My vsftpd works correctly and doesn't allow any random password to be used. Here is the output of my configuration files.

```
# cat /etc/vsftpd.conf | grep -ve "^#.*"
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
local_enable=YES

# cat /etc/pam.d/vsftpd | grep -ve "^#.*"
auth    required        pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required        pam_shells.so
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Do you need to have all the users listed in /etc/ftpusers? or if the user already has a Unix account on that machine it is able to use it to login?

Comment: The file /etc/ftpusers is an exclusion list. You want to keep users out of there if they need to login. I use my regular account credentials to login via ftp, just as I would locally on the machine.

Comment: So I found the right solution, that I need to replace pam_shells.so with pam_unix.so... from what I can find, pam_shells only check that the account exists, it does not really match the password (?)

Comment: I believe that is the purpose of the @include files (/etc/pam.d/common-*)

Comment: I'll try that...